# Deleting a question from the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Is there no option to delete a question in Stack Overflow using the Stack Exchange Android app?

Comment: The app has been abandoned for a long, long time

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the web site via a browser if you want to delete things.